# стоит ли брать i7-3770 для разработки игр

Tags: разработка-игр, процессор

Собираюсь купить комп на котором буду работать в unreal engine.
Бюджет у меня ограничен сильно.
Живу в Армении и тут не многих магазинов.
Я уже нашёл хороший вариант но процессор немножко старенький i7-3770.
Могу ли я взять этот комп?

Comment: поставили минус-объясните почему

Comment: Потому что вопрос не по теме сайта (оффтоп). Но минус не мой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Бери лучше [AMD Ryzen 5 2600 OEM](https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/computers_and_notebooks/parts/cpu/1068556/), он в 2 раза производительней и в 2 раза дешевле.

Comment: спасибо за совет но я беру i5-9400F